# SQLite Database App crash

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial_project) to implement SQLite into my app. I haven't been able to get it working and I see a SQLiteException.

Error log : https://gist.githubusercontent.com/viseshrp/cb24f04d9a913ea75002/raw/bbd8a9667e4ca60b702bd669e9f507f70f4fec57/SQLite-error1

App source code: https://github.com/viseshrp/JustJava/commit/1816b306a7a457943a26530418058aee07927373

Tried removing NULL constraints but still crashes.

Comment: please add your relevant code and Stacktrace into your Question and not on a linked site.

Comment: sorry,but the relevant code is in multiple files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use SQLite keyword `order` for table name.

Answer (score 3):

Order is reserved keyword for SQL statements, it is probably the reason it doesn't work. (ORDER BY)